# Conversion from conventional if else to ternary operator to embed in php string?

Tags: php, string

I want to embed following if else condition into php string.

Here is Code:

```
<?php
    $selected = get_result();   //return value can be TRUE or FALSE
    if($selected)
        echo "<tr align='center' class='selected_row'>";
    else
        echo "<tr align='center' class='red_bg'";
?>
```

Comment: A conversion to ternary is not going to save you much. If this code is used many time convert it to a function that you can call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a PHP ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary (or conditional) operator should do the trick.  Something like this:

```
echo "<tr align='center' class='" . ($selected ? "selected_row" : "red_bg") . "'>";
```

It's a matter of personal preference whether this is more readable than the original version or not.  Keep in mind that code readability and supportability is *vastly* more important than the "number of bytes" used by the code file.

If this is really happening *a lot* in the code then there's a fairly decent chance that you could make the code far more clean and expressive by using some kind of templating system to bind page markup to a model or by otherwise refactoring the page rendering into more generic and re-usable modules.

Answer (score 2):

A conversion to ternary is not going to save you much. If this code is used many time convert it to a function that you can call.

```
function setSelectedClass($selected) { 
    if(true == $selected) {
        $row = "<tr align='center' class='selected_row'>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr align='center' class='red_bg'">;
    }
    return $row
}
```

Now you don't have to have even ternary statements sprinkled all over and if you want you can use a ternary condition in the function like this:

```
function setSelectedClass($selected) { 
    $row = "<tr align='center' class='" . (true == $selected ? "selected_row" : "red_bg") . "'>";
    return $row;
}
```

Once you have the function in place you just call it:

```
setSelectedClass(true);
```

This will save you a lot of code. Anytime you are repeating code, as you are finding that you do, consider creating a function.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said, ternary operator should be the best here.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php :

> The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to `expr2` if `expr1` evaluates to **TRUE**, and `expr3` if `expr1` evaluates to **FALSE**.
>
> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to **TRUE**, and `expr3` otherwise.

If you don't like this one, you still can do this in three echos (but that won't solve your bytes problem) :

```
<?php
echo "<tr align='center' class='";
if($selected)
    echo 'selected_row';
else
    echo 'red_bg';
echo "'>";
?>
```

Or with a variable :

```
<?php
if($selected)
    $class = 'selected_row';
else
    $class = 'red_bg';

echo "<tr align='center' class='$class'>";
?>
```

But ternary operator stays the cleanest to me.