# PHP Conditional operator

Tags: php

I have the following question(project) and tried a million times, but just can't seem to crack this one

Conditional operator instead of if/else statement

age 12 - 19 should display 'You are a teenager'
between 19 and 30 should display 'You are a young adult
else 'You are neither a teenager nor a young adult'

Please assist

Comment: what is the code that you have so far ?

Comment: use a select case or a ternary if block if they've explicitly told you not to use typical if() { } else { } structure but not excluded ternary.

Comment: <?php$age = $_POST['age'];
   $message = ($age <= 19) ? 'You are a teenager' :'You are a young adult'  ;
   echo $message;
   ?>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a PHP ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator)

Comment: LEVEL 1 - I know
I do not know how to enter the third message

Comment: [Place this in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826331/php-conditional-operator#comment47779038_29826331) and not in comments. Then, delete it from the comments area please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

   $age = 13;

  echo $answer = ($age >= 12 && $age < 19 ? 'You are a teenager' : ($age >= 19 && $age < 30 ? 'You are a young adult' : 'You are neither a teenager not a young adult'));

?>
```

Comment: You are brilliant Hardik

Comment: I personnaly prefere @user3284566's answer, since it's a lot more readable !

Comment: @Random but it not satisfied the need of this question actually

Comment: @HardikBhavsar why not ?

Comment: @Random sorry my bad i checked wrong!! yes it's more readable.!!

Comment: don't need ` $answer = ` on a ternary if like that you can just do `echo ($age.......`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo  ($age >= 12 && $age <= 19)?'You are a teenager':'';
echo  ($age > 19 && $age <= 30)?'You are a young adult':'';
echo  ($age > 30 || $age < 12)?'You are neither a teenager nor a young adult':'';
```

Comment: What if I'm 8 years old?

Comment: age 12 - 19 should display 'You are a teenager' between 19 and 30 should display 'You are a young adult else 'You are neither a teenager nor a young adult'

Comment: and that`s it :) if 8 years old nothing

Comment: one variable can`t contain 2 values :)

Comment: Yeah, missing <12 condition :) But nice code, nicer than other answers ! gz !

Comment: <12 condition missing on question :) not in my code ;)

Comment: nope, the question asks "'else: You are neither a teenager nor a young adult". under 12 is part of the "else"...

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard, and with braces you make it more clear.

```
echo ($age >= 12 && $age < 19 ? 'You are a teenager' : ($age >= 19 && $age < 30 ? 'You are a young adult' : 'You are neither a teenager not a young adult'));
```

Comment: Ouch. I see bad habits galore in your future, OP, if you use this.

Comment: Although - I would also prefer other functions, but this is specific what the project require

Comment: @Blaatpraat - You are briliant to - Knowledge come with age(code)

Answer (score 0):

you can acheive this terenary operator

```
   echo    if($age>12 && $age<20) ?"You are a teenager":'';
   echo    if($age>19 && $age<31) ?"You are an adult":'';
   echo    if($age>31 && $age<12) ?"You are not an adult nor a teenager":'';
```

Comment: it is asked not to use if/else statements !

Comment: still no `if` in ternary, and the last condition is wrong, it should be a `||` operator...