# Why am I getting a division by zero error here?

Tags: php

I'm getting a division by zero error on this line of code:

```
$ratio['p{W}'] = ($ratio['{W}'] === 0) ? 0 : ($colorTotal === 0) ? 0 : ($ratio['{W}'] / $colorTotal) * 100;
```

I've tested the above with:

```
echo '$ratio[{W}]:'.$ratio['{W}'].', $colorTotal:'.$colorTotal;

if($ratio['{W}'] === 0) {
    echo('$ratio[{W}]: zero');
}
else {
    echo('$ratio[{W}]: not zero');
}

if($colorTotal === 0) {
    echo('$colorTotal: zero');
}
else {
    echo('$colorTotal: not zero');
}
```

and the results are:

```
[01-Jul-2015 17:40:26 UTC] $ratio[{W}]:0, $colorTotal:0

[01-Jul-2015 17:40:26 UTC] $ratio[{W}]: zero

[01-Jul-2015 17:40:26 UTC] $colorTotal: zero
```

It seems I should never reach this point (`$ratio['{W}'] / $colorTotal`) in the code since the previous criteria is 0 in the checks but it seems to reach it? How can I prevent this error?

Comment: What's this question about? What is `parent::p`?

Comment: Ternary operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator

Comment: parent::p just echos text

Comment: @AsifMushtaq: Sure, I can do an if else. I'm trying to understand why I get a division by zero in the above line of code.

Comment: @ElGavilan: Can you explain what you mean by order of operations?

Comment: @u_mulder: This question is about why I get a division by zero error when it seems I shouldn't since I'm checking before I try the division.

Comment: @rotaercz I posted an answer for you

Comment: Ternary operators are really handy but they are not easily readable when you nest them like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary operators are left-associative in PHP. Your code is equivalent to:

```
$ratio['p{W}'] = (($ratio['{W}'] === 0) ? 0 : ($colorTotal === 0)) ? 0 : ($ratio['{W}'] / $colorTotal) * 100;
```

meaning that `($ratio['{W}'] === 0) ? 0 : ($colorTotal === 0)`
evaluates first. The result of this is either `0` or `true`, meaning that the true part of the second ternary will always execute.

It looks to me like you probably want to make the whole expression right-associative:

```
$ratio['p{W}'] = ($ratio['{W}'] === 0) ? 0 : (($colorTotal === 0) ? 0 : ($ratio['{W}'] / $colorTotal) * 100);
```

Comment: You have to place the semicolon on the outside of the brackets but I'll choose yours as the answer.

Comment: That's what you get overusing ternary operators... 1 nesting level, and yet you're not sure exactly what happens...

Comment: To be honest it's more due to my lack of understanding of ternary operators and the order of operation that was happening more than anything. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start out by adding parenthesis around your ternaries, since I'm afraid ElGavilan is right.
Your one-liner is quite ugly to read, and refers to code we don't have, which means we can't test your code.

I like ternaries... but not that way !

Comment: parent::p is just echo I changed it to echo so it's easy to understand.

Comment: Plus one for *I like ternaries... but not that way*.. You are right, the ternary operator should be used to make the code *more* readable and not to make it *less* readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ratio['p{W}'] = ($ratio['{W}'] === 0) ? 0 : ($colorTotal === 0) ? 0 : ($ratio['{W}'] / $colorTotal) * 100;
```

`($ratio['{W}'] === 0)` means `$ratio['{W}']` is false then the false code `($colorTotal === 0)` execute in the both cases `($ratio['{W}'] === 0) & ($colorTotal === 0)` value became 0. Same for last case division case 0/0.