# codeigniter if no GET look for POST

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, get, session-variables

I have a controller where I have data being sent either via GET or POST either one at anytime but not both, because of this i get error

> Message: Undefined index: userid

this is either due to POST or GET depends on what one is not found.

How can i add a statement so that if no POST is found look for GET and not have the error displayed ?

MY CODE

```
      public function index()
    {

        $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $userID = $this->session->userdata('userid');

//        var_dump($userID);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_POST['userid']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_GET['userid']);

        $data['tests'] = simplexml_load_file("tests/tests.xml");
        $this->load->view('selecttest',$data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check reference for post_get input helper
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post_get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $_REQUEST

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

just check for the variable in $_REQUEST superglobal

Since you are using CI you can also use $this->input->post_get('userid', TRUE);

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_POST['userid']);
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_GET['userid']);
```

To :

```
$this->session->set_userdata(
    'user_id',
    (
        $this->input->get('userid') == null ? 
        $this->input->post('userid') : 
        $this->input->get('userid')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **Ternary Operator**.

```
$user_id = isset($_GET['userid']) && ($_GET['userid']!= '') ? $_GET['userid'] : (isset($_POST['userid']) && ($_POST['userid']!='') ? $_POST['userid'] : null);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_id);
```

***Quick Links***

- [How to write a PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing something of this sort.

```
if($this->input->post('userid')){
 $userid=$this->input->post('userid');
}
else{
$userid=$this->input->get('userid');
}
```

Refer this link for more details : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html