# How to use if and else inside echo statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, statements

I've heard something about ternary operator but I kind of beginner and don't know how to use it, I'm trying to make this:

```
                   echo    '<div>
                           '.if(LoginCheck($this->db) == true):.'
                            <span class="option1"></span> 
                           '.else:.'
                           <span class="option1"></span>                             
                           '.endif;.'
                           </div>';
```

Comment: Can help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator

Comment: Just a quick thought. Just because you can do something, does not mean that you should - It can be all too easy to end up with an unreadable mess. Readability (and ease of understanding) is better in the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the ternary operator is what you're looking for, but you have to chain them to get the if-else statement.

```
echo '<div>'.(LoginCheck($this->db) == true ?
     '<span class="option1">' : '<span class="option2"></span>').'</div>'
```

The evaluation statement comes before the question mark (?) and there is no `if` tag to put before the statement. It's just the expression to evaluate to true/false, and then the question mark, and then the first statement is if the expression is truthy, the second statement, separated from the first by a colon (:), is if the expression is not truthy.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator) for some more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<div>
     '.((LoginCheck($this->db)) ? '
     <span class="option1"></span>
     ' : '
     <span class="option1"></span>
     ').'</div>';
```

[Article about PHP ternary operator](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator)

Answer (score -1):

As much i understand you cannot use 'if-else' statement in 'echo'. You have to use reverse. You can use  your 'echo' in 'if-else' statement. Below code might help you:

```
    $html = "<div>";

    if(LoginCheck($this->db) == true){
        $html .= "<span class='option1'></span>";
    }else{
        $html .= "<span class='option2'></span>";
    }

    $html .= "</div>";

    echo $html
```

Comment: actually you can, the examples of guys bellow are just perfect