# PHP- assign value variable to each answer

Tags: php, mysql

THIS IS THE ORIGINAL, EDITED IN MY NEXT ANSWER BELOW:
I have sent the original code in next answer with very few changes. Ask me for changes or clarifications if i missed something.

What I want to do:
A scoring system that connects to a database, gives some choices for the user, eg age, education.

What I have done so far:
connect to database, and echo values accordingly to each choice. However, it is not convenient to make too many "if && if && if, then" statements,

What I want to improve:
It is much better to build a "foreach" statement, so I have a variable that gives points accordingly to each answer. If age>20, 5 points, if age<20, 10 points.
Then: if education = highschool, 5 points. If education = university, 10 points.

Which would be the best way to build such a "foreach" statement?

```
<?php

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table.
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array(FieldValue)));
$query->from($db->quoteName('table'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('SubmissionId') . ' = '. $db->quote('2'));
$query->and($db->quoteName('FieldName') . ' = '. $db->quote('age'));
```

//  (Extra, but for later: I currently have submission id = 2. It should become submission id = the same as the last user submited).

```
// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);
```

rows 5,6 are age, education, etc, more will be added but i need to find a way to improve this after i fix the "foreach" statement.

```
$row = $db->loadObjectList();
echo nl2br("\n");
echo $row['5']->FieldValue;
echo nl2br("\n");
echo $row['6']->FieldValue;
```

//this is my statement so far, which i need to improve. instead of echoing the value, i better assign variables to it.

```
echo nl2br("\n");

if($row['5']->FieldValue==">20" && $row['6']->FieldValue=="university" )
{
    echo "15 points";
}
```

//should be 5+10 from the variables, not just echo value.

```
else if($row['5']->FieldValue==">20" && $row['6']->FieldValue=="high school" )
{
    echo "10 points";
}
```

//should be 5+5 from the variables, not just echo value.

```
else
{
    echo "not variables given";
}

echo nl2br("\n");

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use switch case?

Comment: Sounds interesting. How do i assign the variables for 5-10 though?

Comment: So you need total points at the end? Can you please post your complete code in single file so I can understand?

Comment: Yes, total points at the end. My complete code is exactly as shown, minus the // tags, which should not be an issue even if they are placed inside the code.

Comment: Check my answer below, let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$total = 0;
switch ($row['5']->FieldValue) {
    case '>20':
         $total += 5;
         break;
    // ... other cases ...
}
switch ($row['6']->FieldValue) {
    case 'university':
        $total += 10;
        break;
    case 'high school':
        $total += 5;
        break;
    // ... other cases ...
}
echo $total;
```

For your edited code, you would replace `$row['5']` and `$row['6']` with `$row['27']` and `$row['28']` and add two new switch statements for `$row['29']` and `$row['30']` with points scores as required (you didn't specify them in the edit)

Comment: Perfect as well, thank you, will upvote when i get enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select($db->quoteName(array(FieldValue)));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('table'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('SubmissionId') . ' = '. $db->quote('2'));
    $query->and($db->quoteName('FieldName') . ' = '. $db->quote('age'));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $row = $db->loadObjectList();
    echo nl2br("\n");
    echo $row['5']->FieldValue;
    echo nl2br("\n");
    echo $row['6']->FieldValue;
    $total = 0;

    if($row['5']->FieldValue==">20" && $row['6']->FieldValue=="university" )
    {
        $total = $total + 15;
    }else if($row['5']->FieldValue==">20" && $row['6']->FieldValue=="high school" )
    {
        $total = $total + 10;
    }


    echo $total; //You will get 25 total points here.
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    ?>
```

If I understood your question right this script will work for you. Let me know if  you are looking for something else?

### Update

Build an array for education.(Where you have fix values i.e school = 5)

$education = array("University"=>10,"School"=>5);

Now make a foreach loop from your result.

```
$total = 0;

    foreach($row as $key=>$value)
    {
    if($key->age >= 20)
    {
    $total = $total + 15;
    }else{
    $total = $total + 10;
    }
    $total = $total + (int)$education[$key->education]; //it will add 10 points if education will be University and so on....
    }
echo $total;
```

So basically you can simply create an array for fix values and get the value from that array using foreach loop and for variable conditions i.e age you can use if else. Hope this will help you. Please ignore syntax error if any as I have not tested this code.

Comment: Actually, the way i did it, with && is not the best way.
What i need, is a way to say:
for each variable:
if($row['5']->FieldValue==">20 +5 points to score
if($row['6']->FieldValue=="university" + 10 points to score
if $row['6']->FieldValue=="high school" = +5 points to score

and so on. In order to increase the score accordingly to each value chosen.

Comment: Give me all the data and your db fields, will make a best way for you. :) @Xarisman

Comment: I changed the numbers to make it convenient for the reader. I guess I am sending all the original code, with my mistaken method && in the next "answer". Thank you.

Comment: perfect, thank you, will upvote when I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT COMMENT: I am sending the original code with my mistaken method. Values 27,28,29,30 are the age, education, years of work, "yes or no" for "has a science degree". If i missed something, please comment for me to change it or clarify better.
As said, each value should give specific points. It is not important how many for now, if i see the method i will modify it accordingly.

```
<?php

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table.
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array(FieldValue)));
$query->from($db->quoteName('table'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('SubmissionId') . ' = '. $db->quote('2'));
$query->and($db->quoteName('FieldName') . ' = '. $db->quote('age'));


// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);


//27: age. 28: education 29: years of experience 30: has science degree.
$row = $db->loadObjectList();
echo nl2br("\n");
echo $row['27']->FieldValue;
echo nl2br("\n");
echo $row['28']->FieldValue;
echo nl2br("\n");
echo $row['29']->FieldValue;
echo nl2br("\n");
echo $row['30']->FieldValue;
echo nl2br("\n");

echo nl2br("\n");

echo nl2br("\n");



echo nl2br("\n");

//this method is wrong, because it does not calculate score, only echoes value
//each fieldvalue should be equivalent to a number of points. if you can show me for one,
//i can do it for the rest

if($row['27']->FieldValue=="over 20 years" && $row['28']->FieldValue=="High school" &&
    $row['29']->FieldValue=="up to 10 years" && $row['30']->FieldValue=="Yes")
{
    echo "50 points";
}
elseif($row['27']->FieldValue=="over 20 years" && $row['28']->FieldValue=="High school" &&
    $row['29']->FieldValue=="up to 10 years" && $row['30']->FieldValue=="Yes")
{
    echo "50 points";
}
elseif($row['27']->FieldValue=="over 20 years" && $row['28']->FieldValue=="No degree" &&
    $row['29']->FieldValue=="up to 10 years" && $row['30']->FieldValue=="Yes")
{
    echo "45 points";
}
else
{
    echo "value not set yet";
}

echo nl2br("\n");

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a switch statement to help you with this if I understand it correctly the script below it will help:

```
switch($row[5]) {
    case '>20':
        if ($row[6]->FieldValue == 'university') {
            $total = 15;
        }
        break;
    case '>20':
        if ($row[6]->FieldValue == 'high school') {
            $total = 10;
        }
        break;
    case default:
        $total = 0;
        break;
}

echo $total;
```

And if you want to make it more compact because you just checking for equals you can use ternary operators inside switch like this:

```
switch($row[5]) {
    case '>20':
        $total = ($row[6]->FieldValue == 'university') ? 15 : 0;
        break;
    case '>20':
        $total = ($row[6]->FieldValue == 'high school') ? 10 : 0;
        break;
    case default:
        $total = 0;
        break;
}

echo $total;
```

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator) for more info about ternary operators and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for how to use switch in php.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you, will upvote when I have enough reputation.