# Not getting login and password values in div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I added isset to my check.php to get rid of an unidentified index error. The thing is, I’m not getting anything in div when I type something random in the login and password fields which is the goal here. What am I doing wrong? I’ve checked the code over and over and I can’t get the right answer

Here is my login.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> MYSQL </title>
        <script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
         integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" 
         crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <input id="login" placeholder="Login"><br>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <button id="entry"> Login </button>
    <script>
    $("entry").click(function(){
        $.post("check.php", {login: $("#login").val(), password: $("#pass").val()},
        function(result){
        $("#status").html(result);
    })
})
    </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Here my check.php:

```
<?php
$login=isset($_POST['login']);
$password=isset($_POST['password']);

echo $login.$password;



?>
```

Comment: `$("entry")` - should be `$("#entry")` since 'entry' is an id.

Comment: Replace `$("entry")`  to  $("#entry")

Comment: Also isset() returns bool [read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). You can do something like: `( !empty($_POST['login']) ) ? $_POST['login'] : NULL;` Read [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) , [How to write a PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Remove the `isset()s` as well.

Comment: after adding the #  for entry im now getting the number 11 for anything that i sumbit?

Comment: alright, i got it working by removing isset and adding the #, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code here

Firstly your .click wont work as youre not selecting entry correctly

Replace

```
$("entry").click(function(){
```

with

```
$("#entry").click(function(){
```

Secondly, in your php you are going to end up returning just "true" or "false" as that is what is returned from isset()

Replace your php with

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $login=$_POST['login'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        echo $login.$password;
    }
?>
```

This will check if login and password is set before echoing

or if you want an easier but worse way

```
<?php
    $login=@$_POST['login'];
    $password=@$_POST['password'];

    echo $login.$password;
?>
```

This simply suppresses your errors, this is more frowned upon though