# Not getting Database users shown in div, logging in with user getting 0

Tags: php, html, mysql

So moving on from my last question yet again i have another problem. Here is the link for that however i will put the codes here too:[Not getting login and password values in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391016/not-getting-login-and-password-values-in-div)
So i'm trying to get the 'number' of the user im logging into as from the input fields which i have made in phpmyadmin. When i enter something completely random i get 0 as that randomly entered name isnt in my database, however when i enter the actual login and password from one of the users i get 0 instead of 1 which would mean  that that user was found from the database. im not sure if i can link the database but here it is: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/sql.php?db=mysqldb1&table=users&token=dbc781132ba546cedab4644522745917&pos=0
here are the codes:
here is login.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> MYSQL </title>
        <script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <input id="login" placeholder="Login"><br>
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password"  <br>
    <button id="entry"> Login </button>
    <script>
    $("#entry").click(function(){
        $.post("check.php", {login: $("#login").val(), password: $("#pass").val()},
        function(result){
        $("#status").html(result);

    })
})
    </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

here is the php code

```
<?php
$login=$_POST['login'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

echo $login.$password;

require "config/con1.php";

$sql= "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' ";

$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$value = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $value;

?>
```

Comment: I'm sure you're trying to learn but you should never be using plain text passwords.   You might as well learn the proper way to begin with using password_hash and password_verify functions.

Comment: yeah, this was sort of a test run as i'm a beginner to all of this

Comment: mysqli_num_rows will never return an id, as the name suggests, it's the number of rows returned from your query.  You need to read the manual of these functions before using them so you understand what you're doing.  php.net is well documented.

Comment: returning the id of the row though that's what  i wanted so the user that's on lets say row 2 or 3

Comment: row 2 or 3 is subjective.  A row with an id of 2 or 3 I assume is what you mean, in which, you'd need to fetch 'id' column from the result.

Comment: well i cant solve this at all i've tried everyhting that i know

Comment: I don't think you've done enough research and training then.

Comment: so let's say i write the login and password of one of the users in my database, if it finds that user so let's say 'simon' it will show 1. which means found. i'm sorry for explaining it wrong

Answer (score 0):

The php will return the number of rows. If you are looking for id you might need to fetch it.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['Column_in_database'];
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm explaining it correctly that's my bad i'm sorry