# how to validate of text item in model window

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check the condition based on input item. This item is in model window . i wrote the condition in model window.

```
<?php 
if( ($_POST['title'] == 3) )
{ 
   ?>
      <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg" />
   <?php 
} else {
   ?>
         <input type="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf" /> 
   <?php 
} 
?>
```

It shows the error below:

> Message: Undefined index: title

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I bet for "Notice: Undefined Index: 'title'"

Comment: users can easily change this to upload any file they want (including malicious ones). hopefully you have a plan in place for that.

Comment: Message: Undefined index: title

Comment: who could have guessed that!?

Comment: `if( isset($_POST['title']) && ($_POST['title'] == 3) )`

Comment: error gone. but two input file will be appeared

Comment: any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition as below :

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['title']) && ($_POST['title'] == 3))
{ 
   ?>
      <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg" />
   <?php 
} else {
   ?>
         <input type="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf" /> 
   <?php 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
<?php
$title = (is_int($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] >= 1) ? $_POST['title'] : 0; 
// This allows you to check whether $_POST['title'] is an integer, if it is 1 or higher. If that is the case, $title will be $_POST['title'], else it will become 0 (zero).
// It will also do a check on given $_POST data to prevent false input.

if ($title == 3): ?>
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg" />
<?php else: ?>
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Documentation:**

- [How to write a PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator) //  Short if/else
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php // is_int
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php // Comparison operators

Comment: this $_POST['title'] is readonly item. the data fetched from Ajax

Comment: Theb replace title with your post and do the validation in your script part