# Setting a PHP variable and getting WooCommerce option at the same time?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce

I see the following code in WordPress and don't understand what operation is taking place:

```
$debug_mode = 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode', 'no' );
```

This looks like some combination of (1) setting a variable and (2) checking if it's identical to the option set in WordPress. Can anyone spell out the logic/operators in this scenario?

Also, why might someone use this verbiage rather than just getting the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's known as a [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator).

However, due to the code style (lack of parens), it's a bit harder to see what is actually happening.

```
$debug_mode = 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode', 'no' );
```

My preference is to wrap the condition in parens, to make it a bit more obvious:

```
$debug_mode = ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode', 'no' ) );
```

Which now looks more clearly like what it is - an *assignment* to the variable `$debug_mode` of whether or not the `woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode` option is `===` to `yes` (which will return either a `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

The "long hand" of what this would look like is this:

```
$debug_mode = ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode', 'no' ) ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

But, since the condition returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` anyway, the `? TRUE : FALSE` portion is redundant.

**To explicitly** answer your second question, "why would someone use this verbiage", - they *are* just getting the option value - they wrote it this way because it's *brief*.  This is a perfect example of why we should write code *for humans*, not just for machines :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and additional resource.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the option in this case, rather assigning the result of the check to the `debug_mode`. The logical operation `===` will take precedence to the assignment, so evaluating half way returns

```
$debug = true;  // if the get_option is set to 'yes'
```

and

```
$debug = false; // otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have many environments (production, testing, development) and for each you can have its custom option for **woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode** key and you don't want to display debug info on production site. Also this key may not exist, that's why you check option with default value

Comment: That makes sense, but if the key didn't exist, wouldn't get_option return false, making $debug_mode = false because 'yes' is not identical to false? Is the default redundant here?

Comment: It is just to show default value and string comparisons for quick check