# How to avoid redundancy when conditionally displaying HTML table structure

Tags: php, html, if-statement, tr

My code is working but I would like to know how can I make it more elegant instead of repeating whole `<tr>` content.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if($condition == true) { ?>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <td>
                        content
                    </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       content
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

So, if condition is `true`, whole `<tr>` needs to be outside of the `foreach` loop, otherwise it needs to be inside of it. How can this be done without repeating the content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you have the an elegant way to achieve this without further changing the structure that you need, however, as an alternative, you could use a few if's depending on what the result of condition is, which will stop the need to repeat the content, and help you to maintain DRY standards.

```
if($condition) { 
  echo '<tr>';
}

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) {
  if(!$condition) { 
    echo '</tr>';
  } else { 
    echo '<td>';
  }

  //content

  if($condition) { 
    echo '</td>';
  } else { 
    echo '</tr>';
  }

}

if($condition) { 
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

You could also use ternary ([How to write a PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator)) condition:

```
echo ($condition) ? '</tr>' : '';

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) {
  echo (!$condition) ? '<tr>' : '<td>';

  //content

  echo (!$condition) ? '</tr>' : '</td>';

}

echo ($condition) ? '</tr>' : '';
```

Comment: Thank you. Ternary solution is pretty nice. I actually had the DRY solution on my mind but it still seemed to me that there is too much unnecessary code there.