# PHP convert check to use ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am trying to convert an existing check for a file to use a ternary operator instead. My original check is this...

```
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) {
    echo '7';
};
```

This works correctly, my version using ternary operator looks like this...

```
isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : 7;
```

I get the error message...

> Undefined index: file

Why is this happening, where am I going wrong?

Comment: try `echo $result = (isset($_FILES['file'])) ? 7 : 'no file uploaded';` . Assign return value to variable and `echo` it, or `print_r` it (in case of `$_FILES`)

Comment: @AlivetoDie without the `$result` bit, no? (if it's only an echo)

Comment: @treyBake  correct, but i used variable that may be OP want to use it somewhere else in his code

Comment: Possible thread duplicated. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator)

Comment: Well, we would need more code to trace the issue. This looks ok to me if you have something like `print_r(isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : 7)`.

Answer (score -2):

This code does not appear abnormal

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : 7;
```

Click to run: https://3v4l.org/PtTmm#output

Please check the location that caused the error.

Comment: Please give an explanation

Comment: Instead it is usually an exception elsewhere.

Comment: Because `empty` and `isset `suppress `Undefined index`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php