# Unable to extract token from url in php

Tags: php

I am unable to extract query value from the url dynamically. My url is of the form `www.domain.com/script.php?token=4343434` . I want to extract the token value from this url. The token value is generated dynamically. I tried this but not working.

**Thanks in advance.**

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
```

When I print the token it gets printed.

```
print_r($_GET['token']); //works
```

Comment: When you do `$token = $_GET['token'];`, the value (in your case, that's `4343434`) is put into the `$token` variable. Print it with `echo $token;` and you should see it just fine.

Comment: ya it's not working for some reason. echo prints nothing. moreover i get token undefined index php notice. however when i use print_r($_GET['token']) it works!

Comment: Then the `token` parameter of your URL is not defined at that time. If you're using PHP7 or above, you can do `$token = $_GET['token'] ?? 'Token was not set';`. "Undefined index" means the `token` parameter did not exist. Both `echo` and `print_r()` work just fine, the issue must be with how you define the value - in your case, that's passing the `token` parameter in the URL.

Comment: As @Qirel says there is no reason for echo not to work, I think you need to edit the question and show exactly what you're doing as something else is going on

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator),

URL : `www.domain.com/script.php?token=4343434`

```
$token = isset($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : "";
```

Comment: Checking for both `isset()` and `!empty()` is redundant. All you need is to check for `!empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Request URL : **www.domain.com/script.php?token=4343434**

By url parameter using  [Superglobals](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp) $_GET with ternary operator and check whether value is not empty.

$token = isset($_GET["token"]) && !empty($_GET["token"]) ? $_GET["token"] : " ";

If you are using PHP 7+ then ternary operator become more simple like below-

$token = $_GET["token"]  ??  " ";

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$_REQUEST` global variable for it. 
It doesn't matter that request method is post or get. It will work on both.

Like:

```
$tokenVal= $_REQUEST['token'];
```

To check `echo $tokenVal;`

or see all the value using `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: I ve tried using $_REQUEST. It prints the value but doesnt save it to the variable.